# Why does my code not working for if the table DOESN'T Exist? C# - MYSQL - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to learn restful apis using C#, asp.net, mysql as the database. I'm trying to create an online book store. The code below, is me trying to check if a book_details table exists in my database. If I run this, it works fine in terms of telling me it exists. However if I change the line `string tableName = "book_details";` to instead be `string tableName = "old_books";` because I want to test the functionality of if the table DOES NOT exist, create it. It just goes straight to my `return new JsonResult("Connection was never established");`. I can't seem to figure this out. Please let me know if anymore details are needed for proper assistance.

```cs
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                string tableName = "book_details";
                string query = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{mycon.Database}' AND table_name = '{tableName}'";


                mycon.Open();
                try {
                    using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
                    {
                        int count = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());

                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            return new JsonResult("Table Exists");
                        }

                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader);

                        myReader.Close();
                        mycon.Close();
                    }
                } 
                catch {
                    string newQuery = $"CREATE TABLE '{tableName}' (    " +
                        $"ISBN int NOT NULL," +
                        $"BookName varchar(200)," +
                        $"BookDescription varchar(1000)," +
                        $"Price decimal(4,2)," +
                        $"Author varchar(150)," +
                        $"Genre varchar(100)," +
                        $"Publisher varchar(150)," +
                        $"YearPublished int(255)," +
                        $"CopiesSold int(255)," +
                        $"PRIMARY KEY (ISBN));'";

                    using (MySqlCommand myNewCommand = new MySqlCommand(newQuery, mycon))
                    {
                        myNewCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        myReader = myNewCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader);

                        myReader.Close();
                        mycon.Close();

                        return new JsonResult("Table Doesn't Exist, it has been created.");
                    }
                }

                return new JsonResult("Connection was never established");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are tryimg to create the table in the error handling (catch) branch of the query that checks if the table exists. Howeber, if the table does not exist, then the executescalar will simply return 0, since that is a perfectly valid result, not an error.

You have to move the code that creates the table into the else branch of `if (count > 0)`:

```
if (count > 0)
              {
                  return new JsonResult("Table Exists");
              }
else
              {
                  //create table code
              }
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to say thank you for taking the time to assist me with this issue. You are very much appreciated. Okay, so when you say move the code I have that creates the table, are you referencing everything in my catch statement? Also what you said makes sense. it returning 0 is a valid response, no reason for it to move to the catch. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Yep, the whole code in the catch branch shoukd go to the else branch. You need to handle any mysql related errors in the catch.

Comment: Although you could simply your code using `create table if not exists ...` construct in mysql. This will only execute the create table if it does not exist already, failing gracefully (without an error) if it does.